# Use CSS3 Animation to move div from top to bottom of screen?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to get a div to expand from the top of the page to the bottom. When the animation starts the div will be hidden (height 0%), till it fills the page at 100%. I tried to do it like so, but none of it seems to be working:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About Me</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    *
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    direction: ltr;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#bar
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 5%;
    background-color: #3b5598;
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: bar 7s ease;
}

@keyframes bar
{
  0% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;;
  }
}
```

I've had animations working before from left to right, but nothing coming from the top to bottom. I've extensively google'd this but to no avail. Thanks

Comment: Animating the `top` property will translate the element, if you want it to expand, animate the `height` or `bottom` property. Also, keyframes are really for more complex animations, when going from one state to another you can use a `transition` and it will have better browser support.

Comment: Pretty quick to do with jQuery: `$("#bar").animate({"height":"500px"},
3000);` Reference: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
.container{
    background:lightblue;
    height:1000px;
    -webkit-animation: expand 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand{
    0%{height:0px}
    100%{height:1000px}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7Aw7/

Answer (score 5):

The title of this question ('Move Div') and the actual request of the OP ('expand a div') are a little out of sync.  Since this SO question is returned by Google when searching for how to animate a div, I thought I would link to a [blog post](http://www.appliedcss.com/animate-div-from-top-to-bottom-of-screen/) that explains how to transition a div on the css 'top' property.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np356tos/1/) from the blog post. Apply something similar to the following css to your div

```
#bar{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

and use onload, hover, or some other method to apply a value for 'top' to transition to.

```
#bar:hover{
  top:100px;
}
```

Comment: While this is depicting another way it still does not meet the OP's requirements as you would have to hover over something to start the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css of bar to:

```
 #bar {
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0px; 
 left: 0px; 
 width: 5%; 
 background-color: #3b5598; 
 display: block; 
 -webkit-animation: all 7s ease; 
 }
```

Then have some javacript to change top to 100% and margin-top to - height (which you will have to set)

This should move bar from top to bottom nicely